# Does not switch to another activity with following code in android

Tags: android, eclipse

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 07);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 07);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 52);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
intent.setClass(this, MyNotificationService.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);    
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

Is this code correct?

Comment: @Henry, you couldn't bother to format the rest of it while editing the tags?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It looks like you are trying to set an alarm currently. Is that what you want or are you wanting to just start a new Activity right away?

Comment: yeah, you are right sir, please provide code for that one

Comment: to set an alarm currently and if dateformat and time equals to current date and time then swith to another activity, this one sir please provide code

Answer (score 0):

Example from [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-alarmmanager-to-start-scheduled.html)

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
      MyScheduledReceiver.class); //MyScheduledReceiver extends from BroadcastReciever

    PendingIntent pendingIntent
     = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
       0, myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager
      = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    long interval = 60 * 1000; //
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
      calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

==MyScheduledReceiver.java==

```
public class MyScheduledReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, MyScheduledActivity.class);
 scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);

}
```

Comment: we does not call Pending intent as startActivity(pi) ,  The date and time format is correct or not?

Comment: @user3320199 Try the new answer